# Is it possible to import data into an existing CSV file using BCP in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, excel, csv, bcp

I am using SQL Server 2014. I need to import data from my table into an existing CSV file using BCP command. By using BCP can we just create the file or we can even overwrite the existing file's data? I need to maintain the leading zeros of some fields. For this I am trying to change the column format into text before pushing the data. But as the file is recreating whenever I am executing the statement, the changes made to the file are getting discarded.

Below is my code..

```
SET @query = 'bcp "SELECT Data FROM tempdb..##tblData ORDER BY ID" queryout C:\Data\MedicalPolicy.csv -c -t, -T -S' + @@servername
EXEC master..XP_CMDSHELL @query
```

Can someone help me in maintaining the leading zeros in Excel CSV file?

Comment: Do you want to append to a file, maintain leading zeros, or both? Can you post your existing code?

Comment: I just want to overwrite existing data in the file as I need to maintain the same format every time. @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: Now you want to overwrite? I" just going to assume you want to append. You can export to a different file then use `xp_cmdshell 'COPY File1.TXT + File2.TXT FinalFile.TXT'` to append two files together